# Listen to Firestore snapshot only once

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `onSnapshot` in order to listen to changes in Firestore. For a certain situation, I only want to listen for a single change, and then detach the listener. How can I do this? The reason I don't just call `get` is because I can't be sure if the Firestore DB is loaded yet in the client when I want to make the call, and onSnapshot lets you specify the callbacks for once loading happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [get data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) you'd use Firestore's `get` method. It works a bit different, because it returns a promise, but the data types are similar after that.

An example from the docs I linked above:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: does setting this work if the `db` isn't loaded yet in the client (e.g. f the firebase user hasn't logged in yet)?

Comment: `get()` will try to load from the server, and fall back to the client-side cached version of a document only when the server is not available. So yes, that should work. If it doesn't work for you, please edit your question to show the code you tried and the results you got.